# Prestashop 1.6 : Use the manufacturers logo as product image

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I would like to know how to use the manufacturers' logo as a product image instead of the question mark (404.gif) when the product image is missing.

I guess it's located on *classes/module/Module.php*, on line 1507 :

```
  copy(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'404.gif', _PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_.md5((int)$modaddons->id.'-'.$modaddons->name).'.jpg');
```

But I cannot found the correct thing to write instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On "themes\default-bootstrap\product.tpl" replace this:**

```
<img itemprop="image" src="{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $cover.id_image, 'large_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" alt="{if !empty($cover.legend)}{$cover.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}"/>
```

**By this:**

```
<img itemprop="image" src="{$img_manu_dir}{$product_manufacturer->id}-large_default.jpg" id="bigpic" alt="" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$largeSize.width}" height="{$largeSize.height}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. I'll try a thumbnail regeneration, though.

Comment: You have to select **"Manufactures"** size **"large_default"** and **"thickbox_default"** on **Back-Office>Preferences>Images** and after **Regenerat Thumbnail**.